# Can I use grass r.mask and t.rast.univar in concurrent processing (threads of python?)

Tags: python, grass-gis

I have this python script:
    if gscript.find_file("MASK", element="cell", mapset=MAPSET)["file"]:
      gscript.run_command("g.remove", flags="if", quiet=True, type="raster", name="MASK")
    gscript.run_command("r.mask", vector=vect, quiet=True, where="gid = "+cat)
    gscript.run_command("t.rast.univar", overwrite=True, input=RASTER_TIME_SERIE+"@"+MAPSET, separator=",", output=output, quiet=True)

But, this processing is long running.
I'd like to execute this routine (for multiple value of "cat") in threads of python. But, I don't know what is the method to run in concurrent threads, multiple MASK values.
Any idea?

PD: I'm not a expert of GRASS. I know python and gis, only

jorge infante
rosario - santa fe - argentina